# SharePoint Online - Lists - Update Field Based On Text From Another Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, update

I currently have a list where there is a column "Rating" that has values of:

- low
- medium
- high

and effectively I am wanting to have another column labelled "Score" fill in based on these values so for example when a list item is created with Rating of Medium I would need the Score to fill in 40-75 -- is this possible?

Have not used SharePoint in a long time so diving back in here and most I am finding is around visual and flows which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Do you want to make "Score" field editable from list forms after populating value based on Rating column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **Calculated** column named "Score" and use the below Formula:

```
=IF([Rating]="low","0-39",IF([Rating]="medium","40-75","76-100"))
```

`Note:`[Rating] is a **Choice** column

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed :) thanks so much Echo!

Comment: Hi Craig Phoenix. I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved.